# If $f \in L_1(0,1)$, then $f^p \log^q (f) \in L_1(0,1)$.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, holder-inequality

I was wondering if somebody could help me this homework question.

Find all $p, q > 0$ with the following properties: (a) if $0 \leq f \in L_1(0, 1)$, then $f^p \log^q(f) \in L_1(0, 1)$.

This is for a measure theory course (graduate level). I have tried using Jensen's inequality, Holder's inequality, bounding $\log(f(x))$ by some other function, and also I've tried using a substitution $x = e^t$ and solving the integrals. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^p \log^q(x) = 0$ for any values of $p,q>0$. Moreover, for any $p \in (0,1), q > 0$ there is some $M$ such that for all $x>M$ we have $x^p \log^q(x) \le x$.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. That means 

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} |f^p \log^q(f)| &= \int_{|f| \leq M \cap (0,1)} |f^p \log^q(f)| +  \int_{|f| > M \cap (0,1)} |f^p \log^q(f)| \\
&\leq \int_{|f| \leq M \cap (0,1)} |M\log^q(M)| +  \int_{|f| > M \cap (0,1)} |f^{p+q}|
\end{align*}

Is this the right idea?